# Show that $\tau_1\tau_2$ of order 2 or 3, given that $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ are distinct transpositions.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Show that $\tau_1\tau_2$ of order $2$ or $3$, given that $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ are distinct transpositions.

I know that every cycle can be factored as a product of transpositions.  But I'm not sure how to prove the order of $2$ or $3$.

Answer (score 3):

Write $\tau_1 = (a,b)$, $\tau_2=(r,s)$.

We have two cases:

1. $\{a,b\}\cap\{r,s\} = \emptyset$. What happens to the product then?
2. $\{a,b\}\cap\{r,s\}\neq\emptyset$. Then the two share exactly one element (Why?) so we can write $\tau_1 = (a,b)$, $\tau_2=(a,s)$. What is the product then?

Comment: For Case 1, would the product just be (a b)(r s) because nothing is in common?  And for Case 2, the product is (a b)(a s)(r) ?

Comment: @user12691: Yes; and what is the order of that?

Comment: The order of case one is 2 and the order of case two is 3.

Comment: And since those are the only two possible cases, that gives the answer you want.

Comment: Oh okay. That was easier than I thought it would be.  Thanks!

Comment: Why must they only share exactly one element in case 2?  And would that element be a?

Comment: @user12691: Since the two transpositions are *distinct*, they cannot both exchange the same two elements, so we cannot have $\{a,b\}=\{r,s\}$. As to what the element in common is, I don't know, and neither do you; it doesn't matter. Whichever it is they have in common, call it $a$.